# SQL- Add Missing data in Left outer joing query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following data
 
Components

```
componentid  title
1            houseRent
2            medical
3            Travelling Allowance
```

empPayrollMaster

```
MasterID EmployeeID SalaryMonthID
1          101     1
2          102     1
3          103     1
```

empPayrollDetail

```
DetailID MasterID ComponentID amount
1        1         1           100
2        1         2           500
3        2        1            300
4        2        3            250
5        3        1            150
6        3        2            350
7        3        3            450
```

Required Output

```
EmployeeID MasterID ComponentID amount
     101      1        1           100
     101      1        2           500
     101      1        3           0
     102      2        1            300
     102      1        2           0
     102      2        3            250
     103      3        1            150
     103      3        2            350
     103      3        3            450
```

To get the required output if i do left outer join between `components` and `empPayrollDetail` I get `null` in EmployeeID and MasterID and amount Columns. How to modify left join to get the required output

Comment: Please can you include your query too?

Answer (score 6):

You need to do a `CROSS JOIN` on `Components` and `empPayrollMaster` to generate first all combination of employees and components. Then, do a `LEFT JOIN` on `empPayrollDetail` to achieve the result, using `ISNULL(amount, 0)` for `NULL` `amount`s.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eea73/1/0)

```
SELECT
    epm.EmployeeID,
    epm.MasterID,
    c.ComponentID,
    amount = ISNULL(epd.amount, 0)
FROM empPayrollMaster epm
CROSS JOIN Components c
LEFT JOIN empPayrollDetail epd
    ON epd.MasterID = epm.MasterID
    AND epd.ComponentID = c.ComponentID
```

Comment: minor changes in aliasing but this works [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16576/4)

Answer (score 0):

As you want the component amount for each employee in the master table you should use a `insull(payrole_detail.amount,0)` or, as @Turophile pointed out, the SQL standard function `coalesce(payrole_detail.amount,0)` for the amounts column.

Comment: `coalesce()` is better than `isnull()` because it does the same thing but is standard SQL, not a Microsoft extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  select empPayrollMaster.EmployeeID,empPayrollMaster.MasterID,
  Components.componentid,isnull(empPayrollDetail.amount,0) 
  from empPayrollMaster 
  left join Components
  on  empPayrollMaster.EmployeeID is not null 
  left join empPayrollDetail 
  on empPayrollDetail.MasterID = empPayrollMaster.MasterID
  and empPayrollDetail.ComponentID = Components.componentid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select c.EmployeeID,d.MasterID,c.ComponentID,isnull(d.amount,0) as amount from (
select * from Components a
Cross join empPayrollMaster b) c 
left outer join empPayrollDetail d on d.componentid  =c.componentid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderID
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName;
```